# Chromium / Chrome extension to improve visibility of “find” (Ctrl+F) results

Tags: chrome, search, text-search, chromium

When searching for text on webpages in Chromium / Chrome using Ctrl+F, the results will be highlighted in color.
The browser will also jump to the section of the page where it found your search query.
However, the results are often hardly visible or even invisible due to different reasons (the sheer amount of text, similarity of color, text size being small, the result being hidden behind a drop-down or other type of menu and probably many more).

I searched on StackExchange, in DuckDuckGo, in the Google Chrome [Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) and on YouTube, but could not find a way to improve the visibility of the search result.

I would like a more visible hint, e.g. an animation, the same way you can add visibility to your mouse (and give visual feedback when you click something).
E.g. a circle could be placed on the screen that draws in on the result.

Is there a simple way to add this functionality?